# class not found during run test with uiautomator

Tags: java, android

There is my class:

```
package org.akovtunenko.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class LoginGmailTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void testClick() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {
        UiObject seven = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.slice.qa:id/btnLogin"));
        seven.click();
        getUiDevice().pressBack();
    }
}
```

I exported jar file  using Eclipse and push it to my Android device.

Where I run this class in this way

```
adb shell  uiautomator runtest /mnt/sdcard/accept.jar -c org.akovtunenko.test.LoginGmailTest
```

I got error:

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.RuntimeException
>   INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Didn't find class "org.akovtunenko.test.LoginGmailTest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/uiautomator.jar", zip file "/mnt/sdcard/accept.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

How can I run test class on my  android device?

Comment: I build with ant and uibuild.xml and this solve problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am build with uibuild.xml and ant  using command android create project